# Using timer with AJAX request

Tags: asp.net, ajax, request, response

I'm new to this stuff, so, this should be a pretty much easy thing to find an answer to.
I have 2 pages, one using ajax to make a request to a second page.
Second page will respond with a sum of two numbers.

My problem is, that I need response to be sent back in 5 seconds during which the value of my button will be changed so, I'm setting up a timer to postpone a response, but I get results back without any delays.

Here is my pages:

Page1:

```
<input type="button" name="btnDoRequest" value="Perform calculation" 
 onclick="PerformCalculation(this);" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function PerformCalculation(sender) {
        $(sender).val("Working - please wait...");
        $.get("Calculations.aspx", function (data, textStatus) {
            $(sender).val("Perform calculation");
            alert(data);
        });
    }
</script>
</asp:Content>
```

Page2:

```
<div>
   <%
    int i = 45;
    int j = 45;
    System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    timer.Interval = 5000;
    timer.Start(); 
    Response.Write(i + j);
   %>
</div>
```

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

Thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it simply by using JavaScript by replacing the following two lines of code

```
$(sender).val("Perform calculation");
alert(data);
```

with

```
 setTimeout(function(){ $(sender).val("Perform calculation"); alert(data); }, 5000);
```